# Mysql Connector .Net: FormatException when trying to execute a command with parameters.

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database

I am using Mysql .Net Connector to access a database in C#. I get an FormatException when I try to execute a statement with parameter. Here is my code:

```
MySqlCommand comm = connection.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "SELECT id_ FROM journalarticle WHERE title LIKE ?title";
comm.Parameters.Add("?title", DbType.AnsiString).Value = title;
MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   id = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
comm.Dispose();
reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: Also, and this can sometimes be a preference thing, but if you didn't know about the using statement instead of calling dispose you should, it's marvellous in my opinion: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/18/447.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it an @ symbol not a '?'

Comment: Does your SQL run on its own, as in returns expected result in MS SQL Manager?

Comment: What? I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you open up Microsoft SQL Manager (Express if you don't have paid for) does your Select statement return the expected result? Select blah from blah where blah like blah

Comment: I have to admit I might be being ignorant here but can you not just replace 'DbType.AnsiString' with 'title' as in comm.Parameters.Add("?title", title);

Comment: Can you mark it up as the answer please =) Why were you using 'DbType.AnsiString' anyway?

Comment: I used it in another connector for unify sqlbase databases. It worked fine there.